# How to call celery task in Django from Fastapi app

Tags: python, django, celery, fastapi

I have two apps (Django and FastApi) that use Celery to do some background task. Now, I need to communicate the two applications and I have thought about reusing the queues that celery uses (I don't really know if it is the best way to do it).The two apps are using the same broker and all are in Docker containers.
I wolud like to execute a task that is in the django app when calling a route in the FastApi app.

**Django app**

celery.py

```
app = Celery("app_1")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

settings.py

```
...
CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE = "app_1"
CELERY_TASK_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES = False


CELERY_TASK_QUEUES = (
    Queue("default"),
    Queue("app_1"),
)

def route_task(name, args, kwargs, options, task=None, **kw):
    if ":" in name:
        queue, _ = name.split(":")
        return {"queue": queue}
    return {"queue": "default"}

CELERY_TASK_ROUTES = (route_task,)
...
```

tasks.py

```
@shared_task(
    name="app_1:test",
    bind=True,
    base=BaseTaskRetry
)
def test() -> None:
    print('Result')
```

**FastApi app**

create_celery.py

```
def create_celery():
    celery_app = Celery("app_2")
    celery_app.config_from_object(settings, namespace="CELERY")
    celery_app.autodiscover_tasks(["Infraestructure.Celery.tasks"])
    return celery_app

celery_app = create_celery()
```

config_celery.py
(In this case I have tried without defining the django exchange and defining it, but I've got the same result)

```
...
django_exchange = Exchange('app_1', type='direct')
settings = {
    ...
    'CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE' : "app_2",

    'CELERY_TASK_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES' : False,

    'CELERY_TASK_QUEUES' : (
           Queue("app_2"),
           Queue('app_1', exchange=django_exchange),

     ),

     'CELERY_TASK_ROUTES' : (route_task,),
     ...
}
...
```

test.py

```
...
@router.get(
    path="/test",
    summary="Test",
    description="Set test ",
    status_code=HTTPStatus.OK,
    response_model=ResponseModel
)
async def test(token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]
                          
                          ) -> ResponseModel:
    celery_a.send_task("app_1:test")
    return {
        "status_code": HTTPStatus.OK,
        "response_type": "success",
        "description": "Test data retrieved successfully",
        "data": []
    }

...
```

As I have two celery instances, I have two workers. When I call de FastApi app, it seams that use one different worker on each petition.

First petition:

FastApi logs:

```
GET /api/v1/test HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

Django logs:

```
I can see the message 'Result', so It means that the communication is working.
```

Second petition:

FastApi logs:

```
KeyError: 'app_1:test'. -> It means that is using the FastApi worker, so it doesn't work.
```

Django logs:

```
Nothing
```

How can I communicate the two apps without register all de django tasks in the FastApi app? Is it the most correct way to do it?

Thanks in advance.